# Difference between Sql Connection and OLEDB Connection

Tags: sql, sqlconnection, oledbconnection

What is the difference between the SQL Connection and OLEDB Connection? Is that OLEDB is common to all (also SQL Server)? To which are all Servers, OLEDB is using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLCommand/SQLConnection vs OleDbCommand/OleDbConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273609/sqlcommand-sqlconnection-vs-oledbcommand-oledbconnection)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The advantage of using **OleDbConnection** is flexibility.  You can change your database (for instance, move to Oracle)and not have to change your code.

If you using SQLServer as backend then use **SQLConnection** for better performance.

check with this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/fadb2742-d75a-49fb-a839-b2d4a9183998/

OleDbConnection : You can connect to any database, which you have provide for that.

Tip: use **Universal Data Link** File

[image]

Answer (score 9):

SqlConnection is designed to access SQL Server, while OleDbConnection is designed to access any database.