# Why an InvalidOperationException for OleDbConnection / C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, oledbconnection

Why an InvalidOperationException for OleDbConnection / C#?

```
string connectionString =
  "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" +
  "Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
  "Persist Security Info=False;" +
  "Trusted_Connection=False;" +
  "Data Source=XXX-LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
  "Initial Catalog=C:\\...\\SqlServerDbExample.mdf";

  OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```

The oleConnection.ServerVersion throws an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException.

I have viewed the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS):
... {database name} -> Properties
... Security -> Windows Authentication mode (radio button), Failed logins only (radio button)
... Permissions -> View Server Permissions -> {computer name} -> Effective (tab) -> everything is listed

Comment: When does it throw the `Exception`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Initial Catalog` wants the logical name of the database:

```
"Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseExample;"
```

otherwise, if you wish to attach an MDF file to your existing instance of SQLExpress you need to use `AttachDBFilename`

```
"AttachDBFilename=C:\\...\\SqlServerDbExample.mdf";
```

A very detailed list of key\value pairs used in a connection string for SQL Server could be found in the docs about [SqlConnection.ConnectionString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) albeit I am not sure if everything there is applicable to an OleDbConnection.

I don't know if there is some kind of requirement to use OleDb, but if nothing prevents it I suggest to use directly the SqlClient classes instead of OleDb ones.

Comment: I tried this ... same error message. 
.......
I have written OleDbConnection code for Access.  I plan to write use this code for other connections like Oracle and SQL Server.  Summaries of the differences are in the following links.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130332/difference-between-sql-connection-and-oledb-connection'

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/fadb2742-d75a-49fb-a839-b2d4a9183998/oledbconnection-vs-sqlconnection

Answer (score 0):

Steve is correct.  This works:

```
string connectionString =
  "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1" + ";" +
  "Integrated Security=SSPI" + ";" +
  "Persist Security Info=False" + ";" +
  "Trusted_Connection=False" + ";" +
  "Data Source=CTE-LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS" + ";" +
  "Initial Catalog=SqlServerDbExample" + ";" + //Database name
  "AttachDBFilename=C:\\...\\SqlServerDbExample.mdf" + ""; //File name

OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```