# What's the difference between OleDbConnection and OracleConnection?

Tags: c#, database, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

Such as `OleDbConnection`   v.s   `OracleConnection`,  `OleDbCommand`      v.s   `OracleCommand`  and more...

I know `Oracle*` classes are for Oracle DB, but `OleDb*` seems works too. I can not find any comparison in MSDN. Is there any consideration of preference to use `Oracle*` classes? What's the real difference between them?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273609/sqlcommand-sqlconnection-vs-oledbcommand-oledbconnection

Comment: OleDb is a generic interface which can work with any DB that has an OleDb provider, while Oracle* classes are Oracle-specific.

Comment: `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection` is obsolote by the way.

Comment: @SonerGönül What should I use instead if I want connect Oracle in C#?

Comment: @TRX When you install Oracle client, it has a `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` file under it's `ODP.NET\bin\..` folder. You can add it as a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated here [Difference  between oledb provider and oracle client provider](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/55562-Difference-between-oledb-provider-and-oracle-clien.aspx) (it's a quite old post but gets to the point) the `OleDb` provider is general to give a database-independent layer to access databases.

The Oracle connection provider is specific and provides optimized the access and bypasses the `OleDb` provider, in order to achieve improvements in performance and scalability.

Answer (score 2):

To be precise you need to understand that `OleDb` is for Access databases or any database/application which has an OleDb provider for .NET.

Oracle* classes are specific to Oracle. Also note that `OracleClient` is the native provider for Oracle databases